# Price range and tax slab design

Tags: java, data-structures

I need to design price range with a low value and high value and corresponding tax slab:

```
low val  |   high val  |  tax slab
---------+-------------+-----------
   0     |      100    |     10
```

here, I want to keep one constraint i.e. for next price range, low value should be equal to or greater than high value of its immediate predecessor. 
Also. I need to keep these value in db (mysql)

Any thought on how can this be done easily with keeping all constraints in place.

Comment: Provide the code that you have so far and explain exactly how it is not working. Your question shows no research, and contains no code. Please improve it.

Comment: I am still thinking on its design. Help with any suggestion.

Comment: Imagine I have no idea what a price range is (and I really don't), maybe you can add a little detail - what it is (please give a brief description), what do you mean by designing it (implement an algorythm, come up with and algorythm - which are different problems entirely)? Can you provide example of several price ranges and how they correspond to each other. What problems have you encountered in keeping values in db?
Are you going to have many values. And share your thoughts on design however raw the may be. Give us something to start off with.

Comment: @kumargaurav You need to implement java-app with GUI or just print it to console? You wan't to get database structure and code that will print this table? What is input for your app?